# Full LIMIT not showing in FQL?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to read a user's news feed and display the 10 latest pictures. Here's how I am currently doing it using Facebook FQL:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, tagged_ids, message FROM stream WHERE type=247 AND filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type="newsfeed") LIMIT 0,10
```

However, it only shows about 4 results when I tell is to show 10. When I take out the WHERE clause with type, then it displays the correct number but they aren't images.

I've read about paging and stuff, but I want to display the latest 10. I can't just guess on a date and display how ever many pictures where placed at that. For some users, it might come out to be just a few and some might be over 100 and that wouldn't be good!

Please help,
Coulton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am experiencing the same problem  but have not found a satifactioning resolution.

But i can tell you why this is happening. Facebook describes it in this blog post. http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Long story short:
You request 10 results, facebook filters 6 results that are not visible for the user and returns you the 4 results that are visible.

This means you have to do a smart check in your code. You have to check if you got 10 results back. If not request another 10 results, check if you have a total of ten results. If not request another 10 and so on..

If you stumbled upon a better resolution please contribute, i would love to know.